# Почему метод extend, не работает в коде в одну строку?

Tags: python, list

Пример рабочего кода:

```
n = int(input()) 
x = [] 
for i in range(n):
    x.extend(input()) ##input() for k in range(n) ---- НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ПОЧЕМУ?
print(x)
```

Почему код не работает если использовать:

```
n = int(input()) 
x = [] 
print(x.extend(input() for k in range(n)) ## ---- НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ПОЧЕМУ?
```

При таком использовании метода, мы получаем целые слова в списке, как будто использовали append.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала приведу маленько измененный код, который **работает**:

```
n = int(input()) 
x = [] 
(x.extend(input() for k in range(n)))
print(x)
```

*Теперь объяснение:*

Метод `.extend()` **не возвращает расширенный список**, как бы вы могли думать, а значение `None`.

Такое поведение в Питоне принято для всех стандартных методов, *которые прямо меняют свой объект* («на месте», «in-place»). Они все возвращают `None`.

Значит, когда вы применили команду

```
print(x.extend(...))
```

тогда **вне зависимости, что написано во внутренних скобках,** результатом будет `print(None)` и на экране ничего не появится.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так, чтобы работало. Для того, чтобы extend "разобрал" аргумент по символам во втором примере, как ни парадоксально, нужно сначала склеить строки из инпутов.

Суть особенности в следующем. Когда в extend подается строка, он ее рассматривает как iterable (последовательность символов). Если же в качестве аргумента заходит последовательность строк, то extend считает каждый элемент этой последовательности неделимым элементом, поэтому на символы дальше не режет. Или, если проще, extend разрезает последовательности только на 1 уровень в глубину.
Объединив строки join-ом, мы создаем последовательность из символов (а не строк), которая "распускается" extend-ом на символы и присоединяется к списку.

```
n = int(input())
x = []
x.extend(''.join(input() for k in range(n)))
print(x)
```

```
3
dflndfd
dfsdfdfsd
fsfsdfsd
['d', 'f', 'l', 'n', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'f', 's', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'f', 's', 'd', 'f', 's', 'f', 's', 'd', 'f', 's', 'd']
```

Дополнительно. Если задача только в том, чтобы сделать список символов из введенных строк, то можно обойтись без extend:

```
n = int(input())
x = list(''.join(input() for k in range(n)))
print(x)
```